# HTML-specific section in bookdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, bookdown

I am using bookdown in R. I have some *sections* I only want to appear in the HTML (gitbook) version (and not the PDF version).

I know about `is_html_output()`, but that doesn't appear to be what I want, and doesn't work except for very simple bits of text. So this works:

```
`r if (knitr:::is_html_output())'
## Some text {-}

Things to say to HTML readers.
'
`
```

But this doesn't (does not compile) because of the tick in `don't` :

```
`r if (knitr:::is_html_output())'
## Some text {-}

Things I don't want to say to PDF readers.
'
`
```

And any R code I wish to place in the chunk fails too.

So while I can use `is_html_output()`, it very much restricts what I can do.

Is there an easy way to have some text--whole sections, and other large amounts--only visible in the HTML version?

Seems simple... but I can't find a solution. Thanks for help.

P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider using [child documents](https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/child/), e.g.,

````
```{r, child = if (knitr::is_html_output()) 'child.Rmd'}
````

Then you can write arbitrary content in `child.Rmd`.